# Can someone explain the weird treatment of the OpenSSL AES-256-GCM authentication tag in PHP 7.1?

Tags: encryption, authentication, hash, php, openssl

I'm using PHP 7.1 and can successfully encrypt a piece of string, like so:

```
$key = random_bytes(32);
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-gcm'));
$cipherText = openssl_encrypt(
    'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.',
    'aes-256-gcm',
     $key,
     OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
     $iv,
     $tag,
     ''
)
```

Then, I can decrypt it successfully with:

```
openssl_decrypt(
    $cipherText,
    'aes-256-gcm',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $iv,
    $tag,
    ''
);
```

However, during testing, I found out that if I decrypt it the following way:

```
openssl_decrypt(
    $cipherText,
    'aes-256-gcm',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $iv,
    mb_substr($tag, 0, mb_strlen($tag) - 15),
    ''
);
```

I would still get my string perfectly fine. With no surprise, this also happens if I remove data from the authentication tag when in base64url format.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Security):

> The bit-length of the tag, denoted t, is a security parameter. In general, t may be any one of the following five values: 128, 120, 112, 104, or 96. For certain applications, t may be 64 or 32, but the use of these two tag lengths constrains the length of the input data and the lifetime of the key.

After testing it appears that since `openssl_decrypt` doesn't allow you to specify an expected tag size it will accept any tag size so long as the tag is valid. Unfortunately it doesn't limit it to 128-96 bits, and if you have even one byte it'll decrypt without errors, meaning that GCM with PHP is mostly broken, as the tag is easily brute-forcable. You can fix this by verifying the tag length before passing it to `openssl_decrypt`.

I'm not certain whether this is actually a bug with `openssl_decrypt` or it was intended that tag length would be verified outside the function, but either way the documentation is certainly lacking here.

It appears that Ruby has the exact same [issue](https://github.com/ruby/openssl/issues/63).

Comment: Made a script to test 10000 iterations of encrypting and decrypting the same text with different keys, ivs and tags. Stripped all tags as in the post. Some of them give the expected result and some of them don't. PHP got a new bug report.

Comment: Has anyone submitted a bug on the PHP and/or OpenSSL side to go with the Ruby bug listed in the answer?

Comment: Yes, see previous comment.